# "Command palette" in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

can I bring *command palette* feature (which for example [works in Visual Studio](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-essential-productivity-tips-visual-studio-code/) or [in Sublime Text](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sublime_text/sublime_text_command_palette.htm)) into NetBeans? If yes, how?

I've tried to look into shortcut settings, but there is nothing called "Command palette". I have Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know of any direct equivalent of the Command Palette feature in NetBeans. In the **Edit** window you can submit **Ctrl / Space** for code completion, right click to get a context menu, and choose **Help > Keyboard Shortcuts Card** to open a PDF of the keyboard commands. But unfortunately none of that really corresponds to the Command Palette functionality. [You could create a Bug Report on NetBeans, requesting it as a new feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-2888?filter=allopenissues).